# Saving player's name and points in a database,java

Tags: java, database

So I am writing a dice game and in the beginning I have to write the code about how many players are there and enter their names.So,every player should be registered before playing.The data about the players that have played before should be in a database.If a player is playing for the first time,before starting to play he should enter his first name,last name ,age and the points he has won each time he has played.

So the code will look something like this :

```
import acm.io.*;
import acm.program.*;
import acm.util.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Game extends GraphicsProgram implements GameConstants {

public static void main(String[] args) {
new Game().start(args);
}

public void run() {
IODialog dialog = getDialog();
nPlayers = dialog.readInt(“Enter number of players”);
playerNames = new String[nPlayers];
for (int i = 1; i <= nPlayers; i++) {
playerNames[i – 1] = dialog.readLine(“Enter name for player ” + i);
}
display = new GameDisplay(getGCanvas(), playerNames);
playGame();
}
```

How do I add the bit here where I connect the game to the database (I downloaded mysqlite) and save there the first name last name age and number of points thing?

I have been googling this for a long time,(not exactly this I know how to google lol) ,I mean the "saving stuff" in the database stuff and I swear to god I cant find a decent source :(

Comment: To answer this question properly would require one of us to write a complete Java database tutorial -- but why should we do this since it has been done already, many times over, and better than we could do, and by folks paid to do this? I think that to solve this you're going to have to roll up your sleeves and get yourself dirty working with database code. If you get stuck after this, then at least you can ask a much more specific question and show your own database code.

Comment: Look for `jdbc mysql insertion` or something like this.

Comment: Wow,no need to be rude man,you could just have answered : Be more specific or something like that...take that sarcasm elsewhere...

Comment: @dambros thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you begin by some jdbc tutorial.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/

Here, you can find out how to connect to a database and make queries (including insertions).

This links explain how to connect: [JDBC Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)

Also, you'll need the corresponding driver for mysql (if using that database). Usually is included in downloaded files.